# Background Image node interfering with touch command

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Im creating a gamescene and it contains two nodes, one of which is the background node. But when a call a touchesbegan command, the registered node is the background node, not the node I require to be moved.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    for touch: AnyObject in touches{
        let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let touchedNode = nodeAtPoint(touchLocation)
        touchedNode.position = touchLocation
    }

}
```

Comment: where is this method implemented, in the scene? Do you only have two nodes but expect the scene to be found by nodeAtPoint? Because as is the code and behavior seems correct but maybe there's some context missing.

Comment: Do you want to touch anywhere on the screen and have the node move to that location or touch the node and drag it to a new location?

Comment: I want to be able to touch the node and move it to a new location. The problem is, that nodeatpoint reads the background node and not the node I want which is on top of it

Comment: In really, the optimum behavior I would want is to have the ability to swipe the node off of the screen, as if it were a scrolling menu item.

Comment: To implement that, you'll need to add a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to the view to detect swipe events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of how to allow a user to drag and drop a node:

```
let background = SKSpriteNode(color:SKColor.blueColor(),size:CGSizeMake(200, 200))
let player = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.whiteColor(), size: CGSizeMake(32, 32))
var selectedNode:SKNode?

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    let point = CGPointMake (CGRectGetWidth(view.frame)/2,CGRectGetHeight(view.frame)/2)
    background.position = point
    background.zPosition = 0
    self.addChild(background)

    // Give the node a name so we can identify it in the touch handler
    player.name = "player"
    // Ensure that the player rendered over the background
    player.zPosition = 1
    player.position = point
    self.addChild(player)
}
```

Select the node that the user touched

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches{
        let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let touchedNode = nodeAtPoint(touchLocation)
        // Only allow the user to select "player" nodes
        if (touchedNode.name == "player") {
            selectedNode = touchedNode;
        }
    }
}
```

Update the position of the selected node as the touch position changes

```
override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches{
        let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)
        if (selectedNode != nil) {
            selectedNode!.position = touchLocation
        }
    }
}
```

Deselect the selected node when the touch ends

```
override func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    selectedNode = nil;
}
```